# Understanding DNS differences between Ubuntu and Debian

Tags: networking

Ok I have a Debian phyiscal machine and a Ubuntu VM.  My question is why does Ubuntu use 127.0.0.53 for resolution instead of the DNS server allocated via DHCP (8.8.8.8).  But my Debian machine does use the DNS server assigned through DHCP.  Both use the NetworkManager service, but Ubuntu seems to require it use the service systemd-resolved, which I can't understand because both of them are using NetworkManager, and only Ubuntu seems to be dependent on systemd-resolved.

UBUNTU

```
## VERIFICATION OF SERVICES UP
vm@ubuntu1804:~$  systemctl status NetworkManager | grep Active
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-06-09 16:21:08 BST; 21h ago
vm@ubuntu1804:~$ systemctl status systemd-resolved | grep Active
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-06-10 13:45:08 BST; 14min ago

## VERIFICATION OF /etc/resolv.conf FILE
vm@ubuntu1804:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep name
nameserver 127.0.0.53

## VERIFICATION OF PROFILE CONFIG
vm@ubuntu1804:~$ nmcli con show | grep DYN
DYNAMIC  4223e640-3e14-43c1-9b70-e59241ff8f79  ethernet  enp6s0 
vm@ubuntu1804:~$ nmcli con show DYNAMIC | grep "ipv4.dns:\|DNS"
ipv4.dns:                               --
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8

## VERIFICATION OF /etc/nsswitch.conf FILE
vm@ubuntu1804:~$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf  | grep hosts
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

DEBIAN

```
## VERIFICATION OF SERVICES UP
debian@debian:~/Desktop$ systemctl status NetworkManager | grep Active
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-06-09 15:37:15 BST; 22h ago
debian@debian:~/Desktop$ systemctl status systemd-resolved | grep Active
     Active: inactive (dead)

## VERIFICATION OF /etc/resolv.conf FILE
debian@debian:~/Desktop$ cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep name
nameserver 8.8.8.8

## VERIFICATION OF PROFILE CONFIG
debian@debian:~/Desktop$ nmcli con show | grep BR
BR0-PROFILE     1cd1c4bd-21bd-45de-9536-c22c261869da  bridge    BR0-INT 
debian@debian:~/Desktop$ nmcli con show BR0-PROFILE | grep "ipv4.dns:\|DNS"
ipv4.dns:                               --
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8

## VERIFICATION OF nsswitch.conf FILE
debian@debian:~/Desktop$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf  | grep hosts
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname mymachines
```

Comment: which version Debian / Ubuntu? Is it Ubuntu 18.04 (`vm@ubuntu1804`)?